# What is the best way to enter data into a small database when mapping tables?

Tags: php, postgresql

I have a small problem that I believe all of you clever people out there already have a simple solution for.  I just haven't realised it yet.

I am a designer for a project and as part of this work I depend upon a PostgreSQL database so that I have one version of the truth.  I set up my tables using common practices such as using a PK (serial) for each table.  When I link two tables together I will use the Foreign Key.  This helps me greatly in sanity checking a design and doing reports on it.

Take for example the following three tables with one field each:

```
student_id : student_name
1          : j bloggs

class_id   : class_name
1          : physics

student_class_assoc : student_id : class_id
1                   : 1          : 1
```

I can input the data using PGAdmin for the students and classes no problem, but when it comes to associating a student and a class together I have to go to each table and find the id.  In this case it is trivial, however when I have around 70 or 80 entries it becomes troublesome.  Ideally I would like a way to be able to input the data by searching through the student_name and class_name field and then entering the releveant id.

I've thought about using a simple PHP form to do this, but I thought I would ask everyone else first to see if there are better solutions.

Best Regards,

Adam

Comment: I would probably create a small php form too

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `student_class_assoc` is a serial

```
insert into student_class_assoc (student_id, class_id)
select student_id, class_id
from
    (values
        ('j bloggs', 'physics'),
        ('m mary', 'math')
    ) a (student_name, class_name)
    inner join
    student using (student_name)
    inner join
    class using (class_name)
```

But there is the problem of common names. If there are two `m mary` they will be both in the `math` class.